# Creating a SPARQL query that extracts information out of a `rdf:Bag` without loss of information

Tags: sparql, rdf

I'm pretty new to RDF, but I need to construct an RDF query to extract some information from an existing RDF graph. In essence, I'm trying to purge existing RDF graphs of the `rdf:Bag` construct.

For instance, given the RDF graph:

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix bqbiol: <http://biomodels.net/biology-qualifiers/> .

<http://omex-library.org/NewOmex.omex/NewModel.xml#_1>
    bqbiol:is [
        rdf:_1 <http://identifiers.org/uniprot/P00742> ;
        a rdf:Bag
    ] .
```

I need to extract the information out of the `rdf:Bag` without loss of information. So in this instance, the resulting rdf graph would be:

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix bqbiol: <http://biomodels.net/biology-qualifiers/> .

<http://omex-library.org/NewOmex.omex/NewModel.xml#_1>
    bqbiol:is <http://identifiers.org/uniprot/P00742> ;
```

My alternative is to make this change in using libxml2 before creating the graph in the first place, but it seems like sparql should be useful here (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Can anybody help me with this ? So far, all I have figured out is that a generic "find me everything" sqarql query, aka

```
SELECT ?x ?y ?z 
WHERE {?x ?y ?z }
```

produces

```
x,y,z
_:r1r21532r1, http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type, http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Bag
_:r1r21532r1, http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#_1, http://identifiers.org/uniprot/P00742
http://omex-library.org/NewOmex.omex/NewModel.xml#_1, http://biomodels.net/biology-qualifiers/is, _:r1r21532r1
```

so whatever sparql query I generate will need to involve the specific `r1r21532r1` blank node.

## Edit: A little bit of progress.

The spaqrl query

```
SELECT  ?s ?p1 ?p2
WHERE {
    ?s ?p1 [ ?p2 <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Bag> ] . 
}
```

produces

```
| uri<http://omex-library.org/NewOmex.omex/NewModel.xml#_1> | uri<http://biomodels.net/biology-qualifiers/is> | uri<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> |
```

Which is closer, but looses some information along the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ?x (bqbiol:is AS ?y) ?z {
    ?x bqbiol:is [ a rdf:Bag ; !a ?z ] . 
}
```

or

```
SELECT  ?x ?y ?z {
    BIND (bqbiol:is AS ?y)
    ?x ?y [ a rdf:Bag ; !a ?z ] . 
}
```

In Apache Jena or under RDFS entailment:

```
SELECT ?x (bqbiol:is AS ?y) ?z {
    ?x bqbiol:is [ a rdf:Bag ; rdfs:member ?z ] . 
}
```

You could also use the `CONSTRUCT` query form:

```
CONSTRUCT { ?x bqbiol:is ?z } {
    ?x bqbiol:is [ a rdf:Bag ; !a ?z ]
}
```